# Android: Matcher.find() never returns

Tags: java, android

First of all, here is a chunk of affected code:

```
// (somewhere above, data is initialized as a String with a value)
Pattern detailsPattern = Pattern.compile("**this is a valid regex, omitted due to length**", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher detailsMatcher = detailsPattern.matcher(data);
Log.i("Scraper", "Initialized pattern and matcher, data length "+data.length());
boolean found = detailsMatcher.find();
Log.i("Scraper", "Found? "+((found)?"yep":"nope"));
```

I omitted the regex inside Pattern.compile because it's very long, but I know it works with the given data set; or if it doesn't, it shoudn't break anything anyway.

The trouble is, I do get the feedback `I/Scraper(23773): Initialized pattern and matcher, data length 18861` but I never see the "Found?" line, it is just stuck on the `find()` call.

Is this a known Android bug? I've tried it over and over and just can't get it to work. Somehow, I think something over the past few days broke this because my app was working fine before, and I have in the past couple days received several comments of the app not working so it is clearly affecting other users as well.

How can I further debug this?

Comment: Hi Ricket, would you mind sharing your solution? My code hangs also when the regex does not find any match. My data is only a few hundred characters long, btw.

Comment: @Zarah My app scrapes web data and the web page had changed, so I just updated it so that it always finds data again. However, I have a large number of non-greedy searches (`.*?`) and I believe those simply extended the find() method to take a really long time (seemingly infinite). If there is the possibility that the regular expression won't match, make sure it is optimized as much as possible. I don't think the issue here is that it hangs, but just that it's trying the regular expression in every permutation possible, which is time consuming even on a small sample.

Comment: I'm getting this exact same behavior when the string is not a match, and the application never returns after the find() method is fired, I've left the phone sitting for hours and it never came back, this has to be a bug.
My regular expression and the string I'm trying to match are very small, my regex is this: "^((\w*\s*)*):" and the string is just 54 characters long with just letters and these symbols: ' and .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long is the string you are trying to parse ?
How long and how complicated is the regex you are trying to match ?

Have you tried to break down your regex down to simpler bits ? Adding up the bits one after another will let you see when it breaks and maybe why.

Comment: The string is around 18000-20000 characters long. The regex matches probably about 500 characters within this. I'm still baffled as to why it used to work and now doesn't. The data string does vary, so I wonder if it just got slightly longer and surpassed some sort of limit; but then why doesn't find() throw an exception or do SOMETHING instead of just hanging? :-\

Comment: I just chopped the string down to about 16000 characters and it still hangs. Now I guess I'll try breaking things by removing pieces of the regex to see if somehow it is broken (even though it was working a few days ago!!)

Comment: Hmm, the regex was not matching. I don't know why that made the find() function hang (and that really worries me) but for now I've fixed the regex and it works.

Comment: Good for you if you find a reason. Maybe it just have to do with the complexity of your regexp and it matching too many bits on the data ?

Answer (score 3):

Some regexes can take a very, very long time to evaluate.  In particular, regexes that have lots of quantifiers can cause the regex engine to do a huge amount of backtracking to explore all of the possible ways that the input string might match.  And if it is going to fail, it has to explore all of those possibilities.

(Here is an example:

```
regex = "a*a*a*a*a*a*b";         // 6 quantifiers
input = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";  // 20 characters
```

A typical regex engine will do in the region of `20^6` character comparisons before deciding that the input string does not match.)

If you showed us the regex and the string you are trying to match, we could give a better diagnosis, and possibly offer some alternatives.  But if you are trying to extract information from HTML, then the best solution is to not use regexes at all.  There are HTML parsers that are specifically designed to deal with real-world HTML.

Answer (score 0):

make some RE like **[a-zA-Z]*** pass it as argument to compile(),here this example allows only characters small & cap.

Read my [blogpost on android validation](http://piyushnp.blogspot.com/2010/03/android-edittext-validation-example.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it replacing all the wildchart `.` with `[\s\S]`. I really don't know why it worked for me but it did. I come from Javascript world and I know in there that expression is faster for being evaluated.